# Protecting database calls within react

Tags: node.js, database, reactjs, security, express

I would like to add database features to my app. One of the things that concerns me is that a well-versed adversary could just monitor the network table of Chrome and hit my endpoints directly.

Initially, I figured I would lock database calls behind an express server to at least hide something but this isn't good enough I think.

In the *BEST* case they bypass my entire frontend and have access to my various database calls. In the worst case they could get ahold of a lot of user information. It would be possible for an adversary to enumerate all users if I just have an exposed unsecured `/users/{id}` endpoint on the express side.

How are these things typically handled? Since the entire app lives "in browser" there are a ton of unique security threats that wouldn't exist in a normal non-one-page-app setup.

**EDIT**

A possible solution would be Auth0 to log a user in, associate that to an account in my database, and then secure each endpoint with JWTs, but I'd rather not end up having to pay for *more* services if I don't have to.

Comment: What you're asking is what every website/web app that allows reads/writes to a database via HTTP endpoints has solved by implementing Authentication and/or Authorization. The fact that it is an SPA doesn't change that, you'll need it too. Could you clarify and give an example of what unique security threats an SPA has to deal with that a regular server-side rendered website doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own middleware to add an extra layer of protection on routes serving up sensitive information:

```
import adminRouter from './admin'
        app.use('/admin', (req, res, next) => {
          if (req.user.isAdmin) {
            next()
           }
           els {
            next('you must be an admin!')
           }
         })
     app.use('/admin', adminRouter)
```